# Resetting flash game in html

Tags: javascript, html, flash

`<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="200" id="FlashID" title="Tank-Trouble">
    <param name="movie" value="TankTrouble_v3.8c.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="swfversion" value="8.0.35.0">
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="TankTrouble_v3.8c.swf" width="800" height="475">
      <param name="quality" value="high">
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
      <param name="swfversion" value="8.0.35.0">
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
      <div>
        <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">                   <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
      </div> 
    </object>
  </object>` I am fairly new to HTML, and have been given the assignment of making a website. I am using Dreamweaver CS6 to make this website, and used the insert media option to put in a '.swf' game that I had downloaded onto my computer. Now, my question is, is there any way to reset that game using JavaScript or jQuery? I would like the game to come back to it's title screen when a button is pressed. I have posted the code that I have used to put the flash game in the document.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Only ways I can see is that either you reload the same swf into your html container again somehow after removing it (Not very familiar with js), or use communication between JavaScript and the swf. In the second case you would need access to the script inside the swf, which I do not think you have. Or you could completely reload your page, which may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Gurtej Singh* has pointed out, if you don't have access to the source code of the .sfw file your only option is to reload it to the DOM.

Assuming that you placed the flash object inside a "*flashContent*" container and that you have a "*refreshSwf*" element...

```
<div id="flashContent">
    <object ...>
        ...
    </object>
</div>

<div id="refreshSwf">Refresh game</div>
```

...you can use jQuery in the following way:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#refreshSwf").click(function(){$("#flashContent").html($("#flashContent").html());});
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: I tried this in the '.js' file and it didn't work, there was some sort of error. But when I put it in script tags in the main source, it worked. Thanks alot Man!

Comment: Glad it helped! :) I just tried the js code as external _.js_ file and it works. Remember to include your _.js_ file after the _jQuery.js_ file. Maybe that is the issue. You can always try easy code in your _.js_ (`alert("hello!);`) to check out if your file is properly included.